# Getting SQL that defines Query Feature Class using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, feature-class

A map in my ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 project has a layer with a Query Feature Class as its source.  I can see the SQL that defines the Query Feature Class by looking at its Layer Properties.  That SQL is based on tables in an SQL Server Enterprise Geodatabase.

I can get at many properties of the layer using the test code below:

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"\\testfolder\testproject.aprx")
mapx = aprx.listMaps("Test Map")[0]
lyrx = mapx.listLayers("Test Layer")[0]
arcpy.AddMessage(f"Layer Name: {lyrx.name}")
arcpy.AddMessage(f"Data Source: {lyrx.dataSource}")
arcpy.AddMessage(f"Definition Query: {lyrx.definitionQuery}")
arcpy.AddMessage(f"Connection Properties: {lyrx.connectionProperties}")
# definition_queries = lyrx.listDefinitionQueries
arcpy.AddMessage(f"Definition Queries: {lyrx.listDefinitionQueries()}")

# Create a Describe object from the feature layer.
#
desc = arcpy.Describe(lyrx)

# Print some properties of the feature layer, and its featureclass.
#
arcpy.AddMessage("Name String:        " + desc.nameString)
arcpy.AddMessage("Where Clause:       " + desc.whereClause)
arcpy.AddMessage("Feature class type: " + desc.featureClass.featureType)

desc = arcpy.da.Describe(lyrx)
for k, v in desc.items():
    arcpy.AddMessage(f"{k}: {v}")
```

None of these are able to access the SQL code that defines the Query Feature Class.  The last part of the code iterates all of the Describe properties of the Layer object and fails to find it.

Is there any way to bring the SQL code that defines the Query Feature Class into a Python variable to work with?

Comment: If you iterate all the `Describe` properties and it's not there, you might need to dump it to a layer file and scan the file as a byte stream of UTF-16 characters (sort of like an `od -a`)

Comment: @Vince I added code above to iterate all the Describe properties of the Layer object but that too fails to find the SQL code so I may need to resort to your last suggestion.  I'm assuming that "dump it to a layer file" is just a Save As Layer File but how do I "scan the file as a byte stream of UTF-16 characters (sort of like an `od -a`) "?  I think that may be beyond me as a Python-only programmer.

Comment: You can rename the *.lyrx file to *.json and open it. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/setting-output-symbology-in-scripts.htm

Comment: The `.lyr` files were binary, with a mixture of float, int, and string. I looked for sequences of UTF-16 characters 0x00 + ASCII/ASCII + 0x00 longer than four bytes. It was among the uglier blocks of code I had written for a customer in 35 years. If `.lyrx` is JSON, then this is now dirt easy, with a `json.loads()` on the UTF-16 character stream from the file (probably little-endian). I'll check this out when I fire up my laptop in a few hours. Might even blog it in Community.

Comment: Yeah - I'm thinking that @Xeppit has indicated a way forward that may be accessible to my skillset.

Answer (score 2):

Back in ArcMap, the `.lyr` file was binary, with a mixture of `float`, `double`, `short`, `int`, and UTF-16 strings. With ArcGIS Pro (as [@Xeppit indicated in comments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/459188/getting-sql-that-defines-query-feature-class-using-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro#comment749826_459188)), the `.lyrx` is JSON. It's even UTF-8 JSON, making it that much easier to read.

If you write a singleton layer with `arcpy.Layer.saveACopy()`, you're looking for the `sqlQuery` key in the `dataConnection` key in the `featureTable` key in the first `layerDefinitions` key.

The ArcPy code for this could look like:

```py
import os
import json
import uuid

import arcpy

tmp_name = os.path.join(r'C:\Temp',format("{:s}.lyrx".format(str(uuid.uuid4()))))
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
m = p.listMaps()[0]
for i,l in enumerate(m.listLayers(),start=1):
    if l.supports('DATASOURCE'):
        l.saveACopy(tmp_name)

        with open(tmp_name,'rb') as fd:
           s = fd.read().decode('UTF-8')
           d = json.loads(s)

           if 'layerDefinitions' in d:
               l0 = d['layerDefinitions'][0]
               if 'featureTable' in l0:
                   ft = l0['featureTable']
                   if 'dataConnection' in ft:
                       dc = ft['dataConnection']
                       if 'sqlQuery' in dc:
                           print("{:5d} -".format(i))
                           print("{:>6s}: {:s}".format('Layer',l.name))
                           print("{:>6s}: {:s}".format('SQL',dc['sqlQuery']))

        os.remove(tmp_name)
```

With output something like:

```
    1 -
 Layer: gis311.vince.test64inta
   SQL: select objectid,nominal,shape from gis311.vince.test64inta
    2 -
 Layer: gis311.vince.test64intb
   SQL: select objectid,nominal,shape from gis311.vince.test64intb
    3 -
 Layer: gis311.vince.test64intc
   SQL: select objectid,nominal,shape from gis311.vince.test64intc
```

But if you're willing to be bold, you could replace the `l.supports()` block with:

```py
    try:
        l.saveACopy(tmp_name)

        with open(tmp_name,'rb') as fd:
           s = fd.read().decode('UTF-8')
           d = json.loads(s)
        sql = d['layerDefinitions'][0]['featureTable']['dataConnection']['sqlQuery']
        print("{:5d} -".format(i))
        print("{:>6s}: {:s}".format('Layer',l.name))
        print("{:>6s}: {:s}".format('SQL',sql))

        os.remove(tmp_name)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the ArcGIS Idea at [In ArcPy, add a way to detect query layers and their query definition in aprx files](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-ideas/in-arcpy-add-a-way-to-detect-query-layers-and/idi-p/1219624), if implemented, might make the workaround in @Vince's answer unnecessary.

The description of that ArcGIS Idea starts:

> We have several aprx files in our organization, and I'm trying to
> iterate over them and determine the data sources for each layer in
> them.  We have some query layers that are commonly used throughout our
> organization for viewing certains datasets in our enterprise
> geodatabases.